# Why embedded structs are not decoded when there is an Unmarshal implementation?

Tags: go

I have a type `ServiceAccount` which embeds two other types (User and Policy). However it seems the fields of the `User` type are totally ignored due the Unmarshaler implementation of the `Policy` type.
  Is there any good reason for this behaviour? It looks like a bug to me because the json package can see through reflection that we have two types embedded and not only the type `Policy`.

I'm aware that I can "fix" the issue by implementing the Unmarshaler interface on type ServiceAccount too.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

) 
type ServiceAccount struct {
    User
    Policy
}
type User struct {
    UserID string `json:"userID"`
}

type Policy struct {
    Scopes string `json:"scopes,omitempty"`
}

// PolicyRaw is the Policy type as received from client.
type PolicyRaw struct {
    Scopes string `json:"scopes,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    s := `{"userID":"xyz", "scopes":"some scopes"}`

    srvAcc := &ServiceAccount{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), srvAcc); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("srvAcc %v", *srvAcc)
}

func (p *Policy) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    pr := new(PolicyRaw)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, pr); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    p.Scopes = pr.Scopes
    return nil
}
```

[Execute](http://play.golang.org/p/AoYMtMxluW)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's a bug but just just how interfaces and embedding works. It just happens not to be what you want/expect here.

`json.Unmarshal` figures out to use the `UnmarshalJSON` method via [this line](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/decode.go?s=10084:10111#L354):

```
    if u, ok := v.Interface().(Unmarshaler); ok
```

As you know, something implements an interface if it has the right method set which `*Policy` and `*ServiceAccount` do. So it's expected that JSON decoding of the the outer type would just call the appropriate method and think it's done.

Interestingly, if you were to experiment and add a dummy method such as:

```
func (u *User) UnmarshalJSON([]byte) error {return errors.New("not impl")}
```

then although `*User` and `*Policy` would now both implement the interface,
`*ServiceAccount` will no longer implement that interface. The reason is clear if you try and explicitly call `srvAcc.UnmarshalJSON` which would then give a compiler error of "**ambiguous selector srvAcc.UnmarshalJSON**". Without such a call the code is legal and the method is just excluded from the method set.

So I think the solution is one of:

- Just don't embed things that implement `json.Unmarshaller` if you want to marshal the result, e.g. use a named field instead.
- Make sure you explicitly implement `json.Unmarshaller` for the outer type yourself when doing such embedding (e.g. add an `UnmarshalJSON` method to `*ServiceAccount`).
- Make sure at least two embedded things implement `json.Unmarshaller` and then <strike>they'll work individually</strike>¹ but the "outer" type will get the default behaviour.

The last option seems like a hack to me. (And btw could be done on purpose with something like:

```
    type ServiceAccount struct {
        User
        Policy
        dummyMarshaller
    }

    type dummyMarshaller struct{}
    func (dummyMarshaller) MarshalJSON([]byte) error {panic("ouch")}
```

but that looks *really* hacky to me).

See also:

- https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types
- https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding

¹ [Further testing](http://play.golang.org/p/xiZpjPPmml) shows that decoding such anonymous (i.e. embedded fields), that their `UnmarshalJSON` methods do not get called.